# Terramaster NAS f4-220 Refuses to connect to anything

Tags: ssh, raid, network-attached-storage

I purchased a Terramaster f4-220 and put it into a RAID 5 configuration. All was working until one of the disks indicated there was an issue (red light on the physical machine). I swapped the disk, and nothing happened (still red), then put the old "bad" disk back. The light went green, but since then I am unable to access the NAS completely.

I have attempted to connect it via the web interface, directly via SSH and USB but the NAS does not react to any external connection. If I remove all drives, it reverts to normal mode and shows up in the web interface.

I have attempted to contact Terramaster support via their website and phone number but I have yet to get a response in two months. I may have an expensive paperweight if I cannot solve the issue.

Any advice would be much appreciated. I've got files locked away that I would love to get back!

Answer (score 1):

After a few Twitter DMs, Support emails and phone calls I was able to get Terra Master to offer a solution. They did not explicitly tell me the issue, but my assumption (based on their instructions) is the NAS software that runs it while the hard drives are in use must have gotten corrupted or out of date.

Their instructions are as follows:

1. Remove all drives, turn on the device.
2. Open TNAS PC software, find your device and open it via the web browser. The TNAS web interface will give an error: "No drives installed."
3. With the device on, insert all four drives.
4. The web interface will now ask if you want to install TNAS software or use existing. Choose to install new. Note: This will show a message stating that all drive data will be erased, but it will not so ignore it (*Yes, this is what they told me to do*).
5. Allow the software to auto-download and install. Set the password upon completion.
6. If the web interfaces refresh and offer a login screen, log in and your NAS should be working. If NOT, and the web interface redirects to a RAID creation page, close the window immediately and contact support.

The steps above worked, and I was able to log in and use the NAS as expected. Posting this to hopefully help someone who runs into a similar issue in the future.